# Can't seem to auto-fill username and password in Fluid.app webapp

Tags: password, login, fluid.app

I would like to use fluidapp.com to make a webapp for me to auto-login to uptodate.com.

I've used (and still use) fluidapp for my email and other websites and it saves my password so I don't have to login everytime. However for uptodate.com, it asks me for my password each time I quit and reopen the app (despite checking the remember me box). It does remember my username but it does not save my password.

I tried the code for userscripts mentioned in [this link](https://groups.google.com/g/fluidapp/c/dLlVJE-ibGo/m/_jkEY9cwsZ0J) but it does not seem to work.
Here is the code I'm using (I used my username and password where indicated below):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name auto-login
// @namespace http://fluidapp.com
// @description Auto-login for Uptodate, username/password stored in
userscript :-/
// @include *.uptodate.com/*
// @author
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
if (window.fluid) {
var location = window.location.toString();
if(location.indexOf("login") > -1){
var username = document.getElementById("username"); if (username ==
undefined) return;
var password = document.getElementById("password"); if (password ==
undefined) return;
username.value = "myUsername";
password.value = "myPassword";
var flash = document.getElementById("Flash");
if(flash != undefined){ fHTML = flash.innerHTML;
if(fHTML.indexOf("invalid") > -1) return; };
document.forms[0].submit();
}
}
})();
```

I hope this helps! Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different -- RE: "using userscripts" -- What is "userscripts"?  -- RE: " Perhaps the code needs a slight modification for uptodate.com to accept it." -- Without seeing the _code_ I'm not sure what you expect to get for an answer. Also, looking at the default login for one who goes to the site for the first time, it may be different for you in that is you've checked the **Remember me** check-box the login will be different. I'd suggest you edit your question adding the _code_ you have as well as a screenshot of the login area so we can see what you see and are trying to automate.

Comment: I think this is on-topic for Ask Different, although it could be edited to add clarity. By Fluid.app, the author is presumably referring to https://fluidapp.com/, which allows you to generate a Mac application (kind of, mostly) from a website, and add userscripts if desired.

Comment: This is not a development question so should not be closed for that. It is about using an app. However it does need more details

Comment: If in the fluid app you manually login and choose the remeber me option, thus setting a cookie. I think that when you start the fluidised app again you will remain logged in. Well it works for my fluid apps for bbc and fastmail